# Resistor breakdown - Raspberry pi 2 Model B Version 1.1

Tags: pi-2

on my raspberry pi 2 model b v 1.1 there is a shorted resistor with a name tag R37. I cannot find a circuit diagram for this particular version of raspberry, so I do not know which SM resistor to buy. Is there a kind soul who has the same model top check the value of this R37 resistor with a multimeter. 
Of course if anyone has the circuit diagram I will be all so happy.

Thx

Comment: Could you explain how you measured resistance? If you measured the resistance of R37 while it was soldered in the board, you did not necessarily measure its resistance; you may have measured the equivalent resistance of the circuitry and components around it.

Comment: @Seamus i used a multimeter while it was on board. but there is visible discoloration of solder around this particular resistor. Also he is getting very hot. I will desolder it later today.

Comment: Absent a schematic, that's probably the best approach. It's disappointing that the RPi Org doesn't maintain a complete set of schematics, and like you, I also came up empty in searching for an alternate source for the Model B ver 1.1.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Why do you think you need to replace a resistor?

Comment: @Milliways my actual problem is that RPi is not working anymore. I think I need to replace the resistor because it is very hot and multimeter says it is shorted. I know there could be damage in other parts of RPi, but I think this is the easiest thing to do before buying a new one.

Comment: If a resistor is "shorted" it won't get hot - by definition a resistor with zero resistance can't dissipate any power. NOTE the Pi (like many similar devices) has many zero resistance components - some are listed on schematics, Resistors rarely (never?) fail by becoming "shorted".

Comment: @Milliways well, I would disagree, if resistor gets "shorted" he still retains some small amount of resistance (he does not become superconductor), and this can generate much power. Also sometimes resistors fail, dont know about these small SM ones, but I shorted few of "normal" ones in my time. I think the clearest sign of his "shorting" is the discoloration of solder ... which could mean that solder has oxidized from excess heat.

Comment: The problem is unlikely the resistor itself. As already mentioned if it was shorted it wouldn't get hot. There probably is a short circuit somewhere else. Measuring a single resistor in a bigger circuit doesn't work in most cases. Besides, smd resistors often have a value code on their package, is that true in your case?